# What is an example of a require-style exception when receiving ether via a public getter?

Tags: exceptions, documentation, require

In the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.20/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) it is stated that:

> A require-style exception is generated in the following situations:
>
> ...
>
> 7. If your contract receives Ether via a public getter function.
>
> ...

What is an example of that and why does it raise the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the following contract:

```
contract pubGetterException  {
  uint public value;

  function pubGetterException(uint _value) public {
    value = _value;
 }
}
```

The unsigned integer variable `value` has a public getter which is automatically generated (you don't have to write it explicitly in your contract), since it is declared as `public`.

If you have a look at the ABI, it looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "value",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    }
]
```

Here, note that the automatically generated getter function is NOT a `payable` function ie. it is not able to receive ether, therefore it will throw a require-style exception as stated in the Solidity documentation.

Comment: So ... the documentation is too generic? I.e. if you would create a public getter function _yourself_ and make it explicitly payable, then the require-style exception would not be raised?

Comment: I have not tested this, but I think yes.